# После установки Docker не работает VirtualBox

Tags: docker, virtualbox, hyper-v

После установки Docker, вышло предупреждение что VirtualBox перестанет работать, удалил Docker, как теперь обратно включить VirtualBox. В Биосе Виртуализация(Hyper-V) включена.

Код ошибки в виртуалбоксе: 
Не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины IE10 - Win7.

VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

Код ошибки: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Компонент: ConsoleWrap
Интерфейс: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: ищите что то похожее на VT-x. У меня в биосе это называется vt-d.

Comment: vt-d включил, VirtualBox переустановил, восстановление системы сделал. Хз что еще нужно ему!

Comment: В cmd Сделал так: dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

Comment: это настройка биоса. Поэтому, восстановление системы никак не поможет (или винда уже зашла так далеко?).

Comment: Не, как ты сказал я сделал в биосе vt-d включил, все равно не помогло (

Comment: Сделал так, сработало! 3. Удалить компонент Hyper-V через PowerShell:

Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
4. Удалить с помощью DISM:

dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
5. Отключить с помощью bcedit:

bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ - Сделал так, сработало!

1. Удалить компонент Hyper-V через PowerShell: Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
2. Удалить с помощью DISM: dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
3. Отключить с помощью bcedit: bcdedit /set

Все три команды сделал по порядку в командной строке PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]