# Не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины Virtualbox (E_FAIL (0x80004005))

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Проблема такая: Хочу установить linux ubuntu на virtualbox. Устанавливаю, а после перезагрузки основной машины получаю

```
Не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины LinuxUbuntu1.

The VM session was closed before any attempt to power it on.

Код ошибки: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Компонент: SessionMachine
Интерфейс: ISession {c0447716-ff5a-4795-b57a-ecd5fffa18a4}
```

Пробовал переименовывать `LinuxUbuntu1.vbox` и `LinuxUbuntu1.vbox-prev`, отключать `Hyper-V` по [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723270/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-docker-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-virtualbox) инструкции. Не помогло (или я что-то сделал неправильно?). Подскажите, кто знает

Comment: https://remontka.pro/e_fail-0x80004005-virtualbox/ не оно?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32800351/6944845

Comment: @Universall скажите у Вас было случайное отключение электричества либо после чего это стало происходить? и еще сохраняли вы состояние машины? указанная Вами инструкция могла бы помочь если бы у Вас были те же причины, но я подозреваю что это не так

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть  несколько, но одна из  причин  неправильный дистрибутив, если хотите мучаться то  опубликуйте  здесь лог, но я обычно не трачу время на создание, а скачиваю готовый образ. https://www.linuxvmimages.com. таких сайтов много и я не рекламирую. там готовые образы.